# Protractor repeated test case

Tags: protractor

I have a repeated set of test cases to be used for different users to check one after the other. How do I do this? I thought of having a function and calling it twice when needed but in that case it will be kinda nested it so it wouldn't work. Can some one suggest me a solution?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "kinda nested" and "would not work", and include some code you tried? I tried to answer your question, but it's based on incomplete context... some more clarification probably helps finding a better-suited answer for you.

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie so could not explain properly

Comment: I will try my best to say the scenario. Suppose there are two users A and B and I want n number of test cases to be performed for each of them but the output must be different.Can I have a common place where I can store these test cases?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating and re-using code is exactly what you want to do here. I recommend you have a look at the [Page Object pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) too.

Take, for example, an application generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) (just `ng new` really):

```
describe('ngrx-intro App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
  });

});

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }

  getParagraphText() {
    return element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText();
  }

}
```

Based on this example, or your code, you can compose your own test code which you can re-use for multiple different users.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly , @Shrinidhi , wants to implement a data driven test using jasmine.

This can be achieved using the `jasmine-data-provider` npm package.

The demo code from the page it self looks something like this :

```
  var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');

   describe('test subtraction with data provider - direct array', function () {
  using([{a: 5, b: 2, expected: 3}, {a: 25, b: 26, expected: -1}], function (data) {
    it('should calc with operator -', function () {
        var result = calculator.calc(data.a, data.b, '-');
        expect(result).toEqual(data.expected);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is the one I asked for. But the issue is I have around 60 test cases to be performed. I am not sure on how to implement this.

Comment: you can have a method or function , which actually loads the data of the 60 test cases as a dictionary and then you can use that as an input. Alternatively , you can use the function as data provider.An example can be found , if  you go the npmjs page of the package `jasmine-data-provider`

Comment: Does that answer your question ?

Comment: I thought of this aswell but I am not sure if test cases can be kept inside a method

Comment: @Shrinidhi They can be. depending on what modules are required.